# Same method in multiple classes but using different types

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have multiple classes that implement method `create`.

```
public TeamScorePk create(TeamScore entity) {
    TeamScorePk pk = entity.getPk();
    if (!pk.validate()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Part of primary key is null:" + entity);
    }
    if (INSTANCES.containsKey(pk)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(entity + " already exists.");
    }
    INSTANCES.put(pk, entity);
    return pk;
}
```

Map `INSTANCES` serves like DB table.
The only difference between the `create` method in different classes are the types it uses. Thus I'd like to put the method into an abstract super class. Problem is with the map `INSTANCES`, because I have to get it from the extending classes. I could declare abstract method getInstances, but I have problem with the type of the Map it should return. If I use something like `Map<? extends Pk, ? extends Entity>`, I naturally get and error when putting types `Pk` and `Entity` into it.

Could someone give me an example or some advice, how the abstract class should look like?

Comment: If the things you put in there will all be Pk and entity, or extensions of those classes, try `Map<Pk,Entity>`.  "ChildOfPk" still IsA "Pk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the abstract superclass generic with the types of keys and values that the subclasses would handle.

```
public abstract class SomeSuperclass<K extends Pk, V extends Entity> {
```

Then you can place the algorithm in a concrete method.

```
    public K create(V entity) {
        K pk = entity.getPk();
        if (!pk.validate()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Part of primary key is null:" + entity);
        }
        if (getInstances().containsKey(pk)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(entity + " already exists.");
        }
        getInstances().put(pk, entity);
        return pk;
    }

    public abstract Map<K, V> getInstances();
}
```

I have replaced `INSTANCES` with `getInstances()`, an abstract method that subclasses will implement.

```
public class TeamScoreSubclass extends SomeSuperClass<TeamScorePk, TeamScore> {
```

Then all the subclass has to do is supply the `Map` (and populate it somehow).

```
   Map<TeamScorePk, TeamScore> map = new HashMap<>;
```

and

```
   public Map<TeamScorePk, TeamScore> getInstances() {
        return map;
   }
}
```

Comment: Now there is a problem in line `K pk = entity.getPk();`. `Entity<K extends Pk>` is an abstract class which declares one abstract method `K getPk()`. I would have to cast `entity.getPk()` to `K` for this to work. Where am I still doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class BaseClass<P extends Pk, E extends Entity> {

    protected abstract Map<P, E> getInstances();
}

public class ChildClass extends BaseClass<TeamScorePk, TeamScore> {

    protected Map<TeamScorePk, TeamScore> getInstances() {
        // ...
    }
}
```